# Require Js loading script that is calling anonymously defined modules asynchronously

Tags: javascript, requirejs, amd

I have an issue where I'm working on a server that is calling a script that loads other scripts asynchronously and those scripts include anonymously defined modules. Because they are loaded asynchronously, Require js doesn't always load AFTER they are called, resulting in a mismatched anonymous define() error. I've tried loading the script that makes the calls via Require, but the outcome is the same. Is there anyway around this? I'm working on a clients server that uses the external script for analytics and I've built the entire site using Require.

Thanks.

Comment: Please provide concise code samples, otherwise it's impossible to guess what is your code doing wrong.

Comment: The question is more of a general question than specific to the code. HTML first loads client script > then loads require > eventually client script's asynchronous call returns undefined modules to the page. Requirejs needs all undefined modules to be loaded before it. I don't have control over the client's script.

Answer (score -1):

It is not because of any problem in RequireJS asynchronous loading mechanism but can be because of the possible two reasons:
a. Since, you are loading a js file which in turn asynchronously loads its dependencies, you need to check the dependencies are modules or not. If they are not, you cannot load them directly. You can use **shim** configuration specified by the RequireJS to load Non-AMD modules.
b. ModuleId(relative modules URL) may be wrong.

Comment: I've since worked around the issue but should have simplified the question. Requirejs apparently needs any scripts with anonymously defined modules to be loaded prior to the RequireJs file or it throws a mismatched module error. http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#mismatch The trouble is that I'm working on a server that calls a script that loads anonymous modules asynchronously and I have no control over that script. Because it's asynchronous, the modules get loaded after my require script which throws an error. So, there is no way for me to load require after it in a reasonable way.

Comment: How did you work around the issue? I'm running into a similar problem.

Comment: I talked to the company that implements the tracking modules and they created a seperate version for me in which they defined the modules.